# Сортировка точек ломаной линии на 2D плоскости

Tags: массивы, сортировка, графы

Есть массив точек с координатами x, y.
Точки разбросаны хаотично, но если соединить каждую из них с ближайшими, то получим ломаную, с началом и концом, пример:
[image: пример]

Задача: отсортировать точки от начала ломаной к концу (не важно, в каком направлении), либо (приоритетнее) составить массив ребер (с концами в известных вершинах) так же отсортированный по порядку от начала ломаной к концу.

То, что набыдлокодил я в состоянии невменяемости, выкладывать с вашего позволения не стану.

upd: Что я попробовал: перебираю точки в массиве, для выбранной точки (пусть будет 2), ищу двух ближайших соседов, добавляю новые ребра в массив: 2-4 и 2-5. При дальнейшем переборе ребра 4-2 и 5-2 отсеиваются как повторы. Но, для начала, ребер в некоторых случаях получится не 5, а 6-7, например для приведенного рисунка у точки 1 будет так же два ребра: 1-2 и 1-4, что неверно и нужна пост-обработка массива для отсеивания лишних ребер. А потом эти ребра еще и отсортировать нужно, пока не соображу как.

Comment: что у вас именно не получилось? В чем проблема?

Comment: не могу придумать достаточно быстрый и надежный алгоритм, а где искать существующий и подходящий под мои условия - не знаю.

Comment: Во первых, достаточно быстрый в каком плане? Есть ограничения? Во вторых, надежный, чо под этим подразумевается?

Comment: не могу пока сформулировать. Что я попробовал: перебираю точки в массиве, для выбранной точки (пусть будет 2), ищу двух ближайших соседов, добавляю новые ребра в массив: 2-4 и 2-5. При дальнейшем переборе ребра 4-2 и 5-2 отсеиваются как повторы. Но, для начала, ребер в некоторых случаях получится не 5, а 6-7, например  для приведенного рисунка у точки 1 будет так же два ребра: 1-2 и 1-4, что неверно и нужна пост-обработка массива для отсеивания лишних ребер. А потом эти ребра еще и отсортировать нужно, пока не соображу как.

Comment: Так а процесс соединения реализован, или сортировка для этого и нужна?

Comment: Еще проблема, то что алгоритм соединеняи двух точек неконкретен, т.е. можно получать различные результаты соединения... Как у вас изначально стоит задача? Нет задачи минимизировать сумму ребер или еще как?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Мне алгоритм решения задачи видится следующим образом:

1. Найти конец ломаной линии.
2. Конечную точку поместить в начало массива.
3. Использовать конечную точку как текущую.
4. Сравнить расстояния от текущей точки до всех остальных и найти ближайшую точку (если есть несколько точек с одинаковым расстоянием, равным минимальному, можно взять любую из них).
5. Переместить ближайшую точку в массиве, в позицию, следующую за текущей.
6. Использовать ближайшую точку как текущую.
7. Повторить пункты 4 - 7 для всех оставшихся точек

На выходе вы получите массив точек удовлетворяющий начальному условию.

**UPD:**

Поскольку в задаче не сказано, откуда должна начинаться ломаная линия, я бы предложил сначала найти геометрический центр скопления точек и использовать наиболее удаленную от центра точку как конечную.

Comment: вроде бы просто, но как найти тот самый конец из первого пункта? известны только координаты

Comment: Вы вполне можете использовать самую левую точку (точку с минимальной координатой x) или самую правую (максимальный x). В текущей постановке задачи нет конкретики где начинать линию, поэтому, как мне кажется, вы можете использовать любую из крайних точек.

Comment: не подходит. Посмотрите на рисунок из примера и мысленно поверните его по часовой градусов на 60, крайней правой окажется точка 4 или 6, но они не являются началом ломаной. То же самое и с выбором за начальную ближайшей к центру осей - центр оси может проходить через середину ломаной

Comment: @Lexanom, А если найти геометрический центр фигуры и использовать самую удаленную точку как начальную?

Comment: о, это нужно попробовать, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

1. Для начала определяете начальную точку (я так понимаю это будет точка с минимальными координатам)
2. Далее от неё ищете ближайшую (для простоты перебором из оставшихся точек)
3. Исключаете точку
4. Повторяете пункт 2 пока есть точки

Можно ещё предварительно отсортировать точки по расстоянию к первой, тогда можно сократить перебор оставшихся точек исходя из этой метрики. Правда, скорее всего на каждом шаге эту метрику надо будет корректировать, надо тут подумать.

Для других алгоритмов, на мой взгляд, необходимы уточнения:

1. Критерий начальной точки
2. Ближайшая точка - это модуль вектора (длинна ребра) или ближайшая по оси X например?
3. Как правильно соединить такой набор точек:

[image: Пример точек]

Comment: опять же проблема в поиске начальной точки. Что если начальная точка окажется в середине ломаной?

Comment: Тогда ломаная будет другой, если у нас критерий - ближайшая. Тут важно условие что есть первая точка.

Comment: вот в этом то и проблема. ломаная всегда будет вытянута в цепочку, т.е. у неё точно определено начало и конец

Comment: @Lexanom, она не обязана быть вытянута в цепочку. Условие `соединить каждую из них с ближайшими` может привести даже к спиралеобразной ломаной

Comment: Это в общем случае, в моей же ситуации это всегда будет вытянутая ломаная. Для наглядности представьте 5 автомобилей следующие друг за другом, они могут обгонять друг друга, могут смещаться левее или правее, при прохождении поворотов будут принимать близкую к дугообразной форме, но все равно цепочка останется вытянута, и все так же будет иметь начало и конец

Comment: Т.е. необходимо построить не пересекающуюся ломаную, в которой каждая последующая точка является ближайшей к данной и при этом более удалённая чем оная?